# Android call setText within onTextChanged

Tags: android, settext

To prevent the infinite loop I did something as ugly as this...

```
    @Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
        int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {

    String t = text.toString();
    String tt = t.toUpperCase();

    if (!t.equals(tt)) {

        setText(tt);
    }

    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
}
```

Is there any other way to prevent the `onTextChanged` from being called when changing the text within `onTextChanged`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use flags that specify if the text has been changed once or not. If it has been changed once, then do not change again, else change it.

```
int flag_text=0;
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
    int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {

    if (flag_text==0) {
        flag_text=1;
        setText(tt);
    }
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
}
```

Comment: that's what I usually do; it would be nice to see if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Guess you mean put "flag_text = 1" before setText(tt)